# Unit ball is compact in a normed vector space - specific proof

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I'd like to ask for help in understanding a proof from a book.

The book says

> > Proposition 1. Let $N: R^n \to R$ be any norm. There exist constants $A > 0$, $B > 0$ such that
> >     $$A|x| \leq N(x) \leq B|x| \tag{4}$$
> >     for all $x$, where $|x|$ is the Euclidian norm.
> >
> > Proof. (...) [omitted]
> >
> > (...)
> >
> > Proposition 3. Let $(E,N)$ be a normed vector space. Then the unit ball
> >     $$ D = \{ x \in E: N(x) \leq 1 \} $$
> >     is compact.
> >
> > Proof. Let $B$ be as in (4) [above]. Then $D$ is a bounded subset of $R^n$, for it is contained in
> >     $$ \{ x \in R^n: |x| \leq B^{-1} \}. $$
> >     (...) [ proof goes on to show that $D$ is closed ].

I can't figure out why this set $D$ is contained in $ \{ x \in R^n: |x| \leq B^{-1} \} $. How does one verify this?

Comment: It cannot be true: $D \subseteq E$ which is a general normed space but $\{ x \in R^n: |x| \leq B^{-1} \}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @mechanodroid I apologize, that is entirely my mistake. The book did previously specify: "We now define a normed vector space $(E,N)$ to be a vector space $E$ (that is, a subspace of some $R^n$) together with a particular norm $N$ on $E$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably $E = R^n$ here so that Proposition 1 is applicable. Your book seems to have $A$ and $B$ swapped round in Proposition 3. If $E = R^n$ then Proposition 1 gives you an $A$ such that $A|x| \le N(x)$ for every $x$. So, if
$N(x) \le 1$, then $A|x| \le N(x) \le 1$ so $|x| \le A^{-1}$. This implies that:
$$D = \{x \in R^n \mid N(x) \le 1\} \subseteq \{x \in R^n \mid  |x| \le A^{-1}\}$$

Hence $D$ is bounded with respect to the usual metric on $R^n$ (and so, as it can also be shown to be closed, it is compact).

Comment: That is brilliant, thank you! I never would have gotten that on my own.

Comment: My pleasure!  A slightly different take on this (when you have learnt some abstract topology) is that Proposition 1 tells you that the norms $N(\cdot)$ and $|{\cdot}|$ induce the same topology on $R^n$. Proposition 3 then follows because compactness is a topological property (i.e., two metrics that induce the same topology have the same compact sets). (When you learn the topology, I think you will find this kind of thing quite easy to do on your own.)